# Where is Casper.js' sendEvent defined?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, phantomjs, mouseevent, casperjs

I'm trying to figure out how exactly is Casper.js using underlying Phantom.js to move the [mouse](http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/mouse.html).

I found that [casper.page.sendEvent()](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=sendEvent) is responsible but where is `sendEvent` defined and how does it interact with PhantomJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since CasperJS is built on top of PhantomJS, you can use any PhantomJS function inside a CasperJS script through the `casper.page` object.

One such function is [`page.sendEvent`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/send-event.html) which enables you to trigger native user events in PhantomJS.

The documentation says the following for mouse move:

> For 'mousemove', however, there is no button pressed (i.e. it is not dragging).

If you still want to see how it is implemented, you can find it [here](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/src/webpage.cpp).

Comment: But it does (by implication) move through a set of other coordinates between point A and point B, correct? What if I wanted to make the path curved somehow, looping a lot of page.sendEvents with coords right next to each other? (to simulate fluid human movement)

Comment: Yes, you can use it to simulate fluid human-like mouse movement. I don't know if it is fast enough, though.

Comment: What do you mean by that? What if I just had a series of `.sendEvent()`s in a loop, would that increase its speed?

Comment: I really don't know, I didn't try that. I would think that you would have to do this asynchronously, because otherwise the main loop doesn't notice that the mouse had a specific path when it moved from A to B. JavaScript is single threaded, so you have any o schedule a little pause.